# How to connect Orange SQL Table widget to Remote SQL Server

Tags: orange

I just installed Orange 3.3.9 on my Windows 7 workstation.  I'm trying to connect to a remote MSSQL server instance using the "SQL Table" widget in Orange.

When I double click the SQL Table widget I get what appears to be a dialog box to configure the connection (Server, Database[/Schema], Username, Password) but all of the fields are disabled and the message "Please install a backend to use this widget" appears at the top of the dialog.
[image]

I tried adding an ODBC connection for the remote SQL server and restarting Orange but that didn't help.

Any idea how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You need psycopg2 (for Postgre SQL) or pymssql (for MySQL) Python packages.

Comment: Thanks for the response K3.  I'm trying to connect to a 2012 mssql server.  Are you aware of a package for that?

Comment: I don't think Orange works with MS SQL yet.

Answer (score 5):

You must install `pymssql` and restart the framework.

`pip install pymssql`

https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/sqltable.html

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation `pymssql` can connect to MS SQL Server

[orange3.readthedocs.io - SQL Table](https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-visual-programming/en/latest/widgets/data/sqltable.html)

[pymssql](http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/)

```
It can connect to PostgreSQL (requires psycopg2 module) or SQL Server (requires pymssql module).
```